# How to include .h files while creating bdf file in Parasoft

Tags: c, parasoft

I am using a Linux environment to for running Parasoft. I normally create the Build Data File(bdf) file using cpptesttrace. But only problem is that i cannot test header files (.h) in the project imported from this bdf file.Any guide on setting up the Parasoft to run tests on header files also is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using Parasoft C++test (latest version).

C++test analyzes C/C++ source files directly and header files indirectly. Based on the your selection, C++test will analyze all C/C++ source files and report violations for all source and header files from the selection (only for header files included by the source files).

For example:

- if the project root is selected, then all source files (and header
  files indirectly) will be analyzed.
- if a single source file is selected, then only that file will be
  analyzed (no header files will be analyzed).
- if single source file and a single header file is selected, then the
  source file (and header file if it's included by the source) will be
  analyzed.
- if only a header file is selected, then C++test will skip the
  analysis (header files are not analyzed directly).

Comment: Is there a way where we can analyze header files directly?

Comment: Currently, there is no such option, AFAIK.